# Passing a date parameter to an in-line Table-Valued-Function is sloooww

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm having a strange scenario with the performance of a table valued function.  Basically, I have an inline table-valued-function that takes a DATETIME as a parameter.

It sort of looks like this (not exactly this):

```
  CREATE FUNCTION fn_MyFunction(@StartDate DATETIME)
  RETURNS TABLE
  AS
  RETURN (
    SELECT COUNT(*), CustomerID, SUM(PAID)
    FROM Orders   
    WHERE OrderDate > @StartDate
    GROUP BY CustomerID
  )
```

Now, I'm trying to investigate an issue where this query is running for >1 minute.  It turns out that if I call the query this way:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_MyFunction('7/1/2011')
```

It runs for > 1 minute.

However, if I call the query this way:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '7/1/2011'
SELECT * FROM fn_MyFunction(@startDate)
```

It runs in under a second.  SQL Server is using entirely different explain plans for both calls.

Obviously, I want it to do the second method all the time, unfortunately, I'm calling this Table Valued Function through LINQ 2 SQL, which won't declare an interim variable.

Is there a way I can use an interim variable in the in-line table valued function?  I don't really want to convert this to a multi-line table valued function.  Other ideas would be welcome as well.  I'm a little stumped.

Comment: In your testing, did you try running `SELECT * FROM fn_MyFunction('7/1/2011')` more than once?

Comment: @John. Yes. Several times. Not a cache issue.

Comment: What if you try `SELECT * FROM fn_MyFunction('7/1/2011') OPTION (RECOMPILE)` in case it is getting auto parameterised? If that doesn't work the statistics on `Orders` may need updating.

Comment: Can you post a copy of the execution plans on the two calls?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with a large ammount of records and both ways returned the values in 9 seconds, no 
diference...

this is a long shot but can test to see if the implicit cast is giving the function the same date value as the explicit cast? try with a date like '2011/1/30' so you would have month/day conversion problems

Answer (score 0):

Adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) will fix your problem.  I have the exact same issue with an inline TVF as follows :

This statement executes in less than a second :

```
select PropertyID from msa_GetPropertlyListWithNoMessages_TVF(DATEADD(hh, -2, Getdate()))
```

This statement never finished execution after 5 hours :

```
declare @msg_age as Datetime
SET @msg_age = DATEADD(hh, -2, Getdate())
select PropertyID from msa_GetPropertlyListWithNoMessages_TVF(@msg_age)
```

Adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the second call corrects the problem.

From what I can tell using the datetime parameter somehow produces a drastically different execution plan.  I would be interested to find out why.